# GAE: How to update 'missing' fields?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have introduced a new field in my records called timestamp.  Now I would like to go through all the old records and set that value.

I have created a REST call and successfully unit-tested it. I also ran it on local dev  environment and it works.

```
@requires_auth
def get(self):
    user = User.query(User.email == request.authorization.username).fetch(1)[0]
    if user and user.email == Config.ADMIN_EMAIL_SHORT:
        users = User.query()
        records = []
        for user in users:
            user_records = Record.query(Record.user == user.key)
            for rec in user_records:
                if rec.timestamp == 0:
                    midnight_dt = set_time_to_midnight(rec.record_date)
                    rec.timestamp = create_timestamp(midnight_dt)
                    records.append(rec)
        ndb.put_multi(records)
        return 'Migration complete', 200
    else:
        return 'Sorry. You have no permission.', 403
```

However once I deployed it, despite the success message, and neither any exceptions error in the log file, I still have the old timestamps. Then I realized the reason.

The nature of NoSQL means those fields are not even there obviously. Hence my conditional `if rec.timestamp == 0:` doesn't catch them.

How can I search within the record object if it has a timestamp field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I voted to close, but I then realized your question isn't quite a duplicate.

The nonexistent field isn't there, so you can't query based on that field, but once you've actually gotten then entity, you can check if the field is missing:

```
if rec.timestamp == None:
```

Comment: Yeah, the linked question claims there was no solution to this. Yet your solution works great. Thanks a lot. :)  You can always un-close a question, so I believe.

Comment: There is 'no solution' in the sense that there is no efficient way to do it. The only way (in particular when you have a lot of entities) is to get all the entities paginated from a task queue until you process them all. Imagine you have 10million entities and only one is missing the field, you still have to get all of them just to find that one.